# sbt publish spray example apps to local maven repository

Tags: scala, osgi, sbt, apache-karaf, spray

I am new to `maven` and I am trying to figure out how to `sbt publish` [spray examples apps](https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/master/examples) to the my local `maven` repository. I am able to publish the spray projects but not the example apps. I got the spray projects to `sbt publish` by changing `publishTo` in `BuildSettings.scala` as such

```
 lazy val sprayModuleSettings =
    basicSettings ++ formatSettings ++
    NightlyBuildSupport.settings ++
    net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings ++
    seq(
      // scaladoc settings
      (scalacOptions in doc) <++= (name, version).map { (n, v) => Seq("-doc-title", n, "-doc-version", v) },

      // publishing
      crossPaths := false,
      publishMavenStyle := true,
      publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))
    )
```

Any ideas on how to publish the example apps?

**Update**
After tinkering with this for a bit, "sbt package" creates the jar files for the example apps, now I guess I can use maven to deploy it to my local repo?

Comment: did you try sbt publish-local?

Comment: I did but that published to ivy2 cache instead plus it also didn't publish the example apps.

Comment: Don't know much about the SBT stuff, but after you have your application successfull in your local Maven Repository you just need to install it either via commandline: install mvn:groupID/artifactID/version/identifier or by installing a feature which contains the bundles. Another way for testing at least would be to install from local filesystem, but I'm sure you already tried this or by using the deployment. Installing from filesystem is almost the same as the maven one: install file:location

Comment: Thanks Achim, I eventually did it this way using `install file:location`.

Answer (score 1):

In the build publishing is purposely disabled for examples in this line (same file):

```
lazy val exampleSettings = basicSettings ++ noPublishing
```

Try removing `++ noPublishing`.

Comment: Thanks, that got passed my initial problem, now I am seeing new errors, just need to find the right build setting to tweak, e.g.,
`(examples/*:publish-configuration) Repository for publishing is not specified. [error] (spray-client-examples/*:publish-configuration) Repository for publishing is not specified.`